# Cannot convert from IGenericReporsitoty<Entity> to IGenericReporsitoty<EntityBase>

Tags: c#, .net-core, typeconverter

I am having an error in my Controller. The repository can't be injected in the base constructor

```
public class MyController : ControllerCRUDBase<Entity, TournamentDto>
{
    public MyController (IGenericRepository<Entity> repository, IMapper mapper) 
        : base(repository, mapper)
    {
    }
}
```

Where my ControllerCRUDBase is:

```
public abstract class ControllerCRUDBase<E, D> : ControllerBase
        where E : EntityBase
        where D : DtoBase
    {
        protected readonly IGenericRepository<EntityBase> _repository;
        protected readonly IMapper _mapper;

        public ControllerCRUDBase(IGenericRepository<EntityBase> repository,
                                  IMapper mapper)
        {
            _repository = repository;
            _mapper = mapper;
        }
```

My IGenericRepository is:

```
public interface IGenericRepository<TEntity> where TEntity : EntityBase
    {
    }
```

And the Entity class is:

```
public class Entity: EntityBase
{
}
```

The error is this:

```
cannot convert from 'IGenericRepository<Entity>' to 'IGenericRepository<EntityBase>'
```

And I can't understand why.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're defining a constraint on the generic parameter `E` for `ControllerCRUDBase`, but then directly referencing `EntityBase` in the subsequent constructor instead. Try the following:

```
public abstract class ControllerCRUDBase<E, D> : ControllerBase
        where E : EntityBase
        where D : DtoBase
    {
        protected readonly IGenericRepository<E> _repository;
        protected readonly IMapper _mapper;

        public ControllerCRUDBase(IGenericRepository<E> repository,
                                  IMapper mapper)
        {
            _repository = repository;
            _mapper = mapper;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem you are running into is due to something called generic [variance](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/generics/covariance-and-contravariance). A variable of type `IGenericRepository<Entity>` cannot be assigned to `IGenericRepository<EntityBase>` or vice versa. One is simply not the other--despite the relationship between `Entity` and `EntityBase`--because your interface is currently **invariant**.

```
public interface IGenericRepository<TEntity> where TEntity : EntityBase
{
}

IGenericRepository<Entity> e =...;
IGenericRepository<EntityBase> b = e; // disallowed CS0266
```

If you repository interface were **covariant** (declared with the `out` modifier), the assignment would be possible:

```
public interface IGenericRepository<out TEntity> where TEntity : EntityBase
{
}

IGenericRepository<Entity> e =...;
IGenericRepository<EntityBase> b = e; // allowed
```

However, that may not be possible here. You haven't shown the body of the interfaces, but my guess is that you use `TEntity` as both a return type and a parameter type, which makes your interface invariant by nature.